# AngularJS Directive template not displaying HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/skwidgets/w2X9m/3/ to build out a group of check boxes.  It works just as desired in the prototype and I can even include more then one group and they run independently.  As I was satisfied I add the code to the app that I am building and the html in the template: '<>' of the directive does not appear.  the model data that is in the handle bars in the template does how ever.  I cannot seam to figure out why as there are not errors.

I also have this plunker that shows the code working
http://plnkr.co/edit/JE5dRDU4VyGd0UAbCtNu?p=preview

```
<div class="sqs" >
        <pre>
            {{survey | json}}
        </pre>

        <suvey-checkbox ng-model="Q1" ng-init="surveyQuestions = [
                { 'value':'value1', 'name': 'The unit' }, 
                { 'value': 'value2', 'name': 'Patient Threw Up'}, 
                { 'value':'value3', 'name': 'Unsafe for children' }, 
                { 'value':'value4', 'name': 'Actively dying, reached life goal'}]">
        </suvey-checkbox>

        <suvey-checkbox ng-model="Q2" ng-init="surveyQuestions = [
                { 'value':'value1', 'name': 'The unit' }, 
                { 'value': 'value2', 'name': 'Patient Threw Up'}, 
                { 'value':'value3', 'name': 'Unsafe for children' }, 
                { 'value':'value4', 'name': 'Actively dying, reached life goal'}]">
        </suvey-checkbox>
</div>
```

And

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.run(function($rootScope){
$rootScope.survey = [];
});

app.directive('suveyCheckbox', function ($rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^ngModel',
    scope: {
        ngModel: '@'
    },
    template: '{{ngModel}}<br /><label ng-repeat="surveyQuestion in      surveyQuestions" class="checkbox">' +
                '<input data-role="none" type="checkbox" name="selectedExclusion[]" value="{{surveyQuestion.value}}"' + 
                'ng-checked="surveyAnswers.indexOf(surveyQuestion.value) > -1" ng-click="togglesurveyAnswers(surveyQuestion.value)"> ' +
                '{{surveyQuestion.name}} <br /></label>{{surveyAnswers}}',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
        // selected exclusion
        scope.surveyAnswers = [];

        // toggle surveyAnswers for a given answer by name
        scope.togglesurveyAnswers = function togglesurveyAnswers(surveyQuestion) {
            var idx = scope.surveyAnswers.indexOf(surveyQuestion);

            // is currently selected
            if (idx > -1) {
                scope.surveyAnswers.splice(idx, 1);
            }
            // is newly selected
                else {
                scope.surveyAnswers.push(surveyQuestion);
            }
        };
        $rootScope.survey.push(scope.surveyAnswers);
    }
}
});
```

I took the code from the prototype in the fiddler that is linked and that is not working for some reason.

Comment: What is your question exactly? I'm a little confused. I took your fiddle and made it work and corrected a misspelling in your directive name, unless you meant for 'suvey' instead of 'survey', see the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2X9m/8/)

Comment: Thank you for the correction and the working fiddle.  The issue is that the same code when put in to the app that I am building only does not do anything with the html that is template: value in the directive.  The page displays the modal names (bedsideQ1, bedsideQ1) and two empty obects ( [],[] ).  No check boxes are populated.  I cannot figure out why.

Comment: I can't explain why right now, but your original fiddle was including AngularJS 1.2 while your plunker was 1.1.5, I copied your plunker source link into the fiddle, amoung other things. Anyway I just opened the fiddle again and changed AngularJS source to the latest 1.2.4 and got the same empty bracket issue again. So try making sure that your app is 1.1.5, if that works then it is a version issue. I'd look to see if injections are needed or if deprecation is the issue

Answer (score 0):

The code will not work in newer versions of angular. In previous versions there was a bug that caused isolate scope to not be really isolate and leak out to other directives.

In angular 1.2.x isolate scope is truly isolate. This means that you cannot use anything in your template unless the directive either put it manually into the scope or it is included in the isolate scope definition (e.g. `scope: { myVar: '='}`)

For example, in your case your template cannot access `surveyQuestions` because it was not defined in the private scope (ng-init will not be able to access the isolate scope inside of your `surveyCheckbox` directive.

If you want to be able to use `surveyQuestions` in your directive's template you need to pass it in to the isolate scope:

```
<survey-checkbox questions="surveyQuestions" ng-model="bedsideQ2" ng-init="surveyQuestions = [
                { 'value':'value1', 'name': 'The unit' }, 
                { 'value': 'value2', 'name': 'Patient Threw Up'}, 
                { 'value':'value3', 'name': 'Unsafe for children' }, 
                { 'value':'value4', 'name': 'Actively dying, reached life goal'}]">
</survey-checkbox>
```

And then add it to your isolate scope:

```
scope: {
   ngModel: '@',
   surveyQuestions: '=questions'
}
```